# confusion on an error in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

Recently i made an app for android through android studio, a very simple app.
But when i started the emulator to test the app i received an unusual error.
This is what the error looks like in a general form :-

> WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:155:Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\xxxxxxx.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_23.ini for reading.

**My question is,**

**1) What is the meaning of this error ?**

**2) And how do i solve this error ?**

Comment: Try deleting the AVD and re-creating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you recently updated the SDK tools. It sounds like it might be some compatibility issue with the tools and the emulator. Try going into the AVD manager and see if there is an update, and/or delete the emulator and re-create and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: actually, the issue got solved when i made a new variable under the name ANDROID_SDK_HOME and set its directory to .android in my c drive.